# Is there a more straightforward way to delete a nested path using cloud-functions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code that proves to be really stable in deleting nested data from Firestore. However, I have a concern since it is using the Firebase token. I mean, is there a more straightforward way to eradicate nested collections using a cloud function ?  or would you consider this to be a good solution. I am using this code when I user is deleting his account and due to some GPDR regulations, I need to make sure that no data are left and I don't want to use any extinctions.

```js
// recursive delete function..
export const recursiveDeleteClients = functions
  .runWith({
timeoutSeconds: 300,
memory: '512MB',
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
await firebase_tools.firestore.delete('data-personal-data/${context.auth?.uid}/nested-data/', {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      yes: true,
      token: functions.config().fb.token, // firebase tools generated token
      force: true,
  });
  return null;
});
```

Comment: You'll find lots of options if you just web search for "firestore delete collection".  For example, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#node.js_2) or the other [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) that you likely copied from. Pick the one you like best.  Opinions (e.g. "is it good?") are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is your concern with the fact that this code uses a token? Also: what is the value of that token? If it is about who can invoke this Cloud Function, consider implementing the security measure that are in the code sample in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Comment: @DougStevenson I implanted this code before almost one year, as I mentioned it is Stable and it was in the docs, but I am kind of looking for more reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about who can call this Cloud Function to delete data, consider implementing the security measure that is present in the code sample in the documentation on [deleting collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) on which the code you use is based:

```
exports.recursiveDelete = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    //  This part is missing in your code
    // Only allow admin users to execute this function.
    if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token && context.auth.token.admin)) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'permission-denied',
        'Must be an administrative user to initiate delete.'
      );
    }
    // 

    const path = data.path;
    console.log(
      `User ${context.auth.uid} has requested to delete path ${path}`
    );

    // Run a recursive delete on the given document or collection path.
    // The 'token' must be set in the functions config, and can be generated
    // at the command line by running 'firebase login:ci'.
    await firebase_tools.firestore
      ...
```

Comment: This is exactly my issue here since the client is calling the function not the admin, and my concerns are if it’s a good thing to allow the token to be so available.

Comment: Because I want to use it when a user is deleting his own data.

Comment: I would rather then use an approach that will query the collection and delete each doc separately.. right?

Comment: Since you use `context.auth?.uid`, you're already only allowing the user to delete their own data. There is no way for them to send a fake `uid`, unless they have access to your project's administrative credentials (in which case you already have much bigger problems than this). --- You **can** delete the documents from the client-side application too, but can't call `firebase_tools` there - so will have to delete them one by one indeed. That may use more bandwidth and take more time, so measure the results you get and decide if that is acceptable for your users.

Comment: Thanks for claryfijg I will then keep using this implementation, don’t want to involve client side since all deletes are disabled, I was confused regarding me using the token to initiate the recursive delete since it don’t make any scenes to me why I should be using the token and why such ops cannot be done without the token, for the record I have it implemented in 2 ways one for single docs , the other for multi .. by targeting the doc or targeting his direct parent..